# ファイルの内容を読み込みnode-gzipで利用したい

Tags: javascript, node.js, gzip

[node-gzip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gzip)でJavaScriptでファイルを圧縮してサーバーに転送を考えています。
このページの下記のように（＜READMEより抜粋＞参照）、テキストをインプットとした場合の記載があります。
（ここでは'Hello World'）
このテキストの部分をファイルを指定して、圧縮したいので、'Hello World'をfileA.txtのように置き換えたのですがエラーになりました。
大変初歩的な質問で恐縮ですが、ご教授いただければと思います。

＜READMEより抜粋＞

```js
const {gzip, ungzip} = require('node-gzip');
const compressed = await gzip('Hello World');
const decompressed = await ungzip(compressed);
console.log(decompressed.toString());        //Hello World
```

Comment: 確認ですが、これは Node.js 上で実行するコードという事で間違い無いですよね？
つまり、クライアント（ブラウザ）側では無いですよね？
「サーバーに転送」という部分が気になったので念のため。

Comment: 「いま、クライアント（ブラウザ）側を開発しております。」との事です（私の回答へのコメントより）。
今から質問を編集して整合性を取るのも難しいと思いますので、質問は編集しないでおきます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`node-gzip` は [README](https://github.com/Rebsos/node-gzip#description) によると、

> `Buffer | TypedArray | DataView | ArrayBuffer | string`

を受け付けます。[fs.readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilepath-options-callback) がファイルの内容を `string` か `Buffer` で返すので、これでよさそうです。

```js
const fs = require('node:fs/promises');
const { gzip, ungzip } = require('node-gzip');

;(async function() {
    const data = await fs.readFile("hello.txt");
    const compressed = await gzip(data);
    const decompressed = await ungzip(compressed);
    console.log(decompressed.toString());
})()
```

---

接頭辞 `node:` が使えないバージョンの Node.js を使用している場合は、下のように接頭辞を付けずにモジュールを指定します。ただし、`/promises` は削りません。

```js
const fs = require('fs/promises');
```

---

#### クライアント（ブラウザ）側で動かしたい場合

それは無理です。
クライアント（ブラウザ）に Node.js の API は実装されていません。 ですから、`zlib` モジュールも、それに依存している `node-gzip` モジュールも動きません。 `fs` モジュールに関してはセキュリティーやプライバシーを考えれば解り易いと思います。 ファイル名を指定してユーザーのマシンのファイルを読み書きできてしまうと大変な事です。

そういう訳ですから、質問の通りの構成ですとあきらめるしかありません。ただ、

- ユーザーにファイルを送信してもらう
- その際、圧縮してもらう

という事がまったく不可能というわけでは有りません。「ファイル（やデータ）の POST」といったキーワードで検索してみて下さい。（圧縮のことは一旦忘れて完成させた方がよいでしょう）

Comment: 早速のご回答ありがとうございます！
上記のコードを追加して（まずは最初の2行）npm run serveを実行しました。その際に下記エラーがでてしまいました。こちらは私の設定がよろしくないのかと思いますが、変更箇所などアドバイスを頂ければと思います。

This dependency was not found:

Comment: v14.16.1
になります。

Comment: 下記のエラーが出ました。
Uncaught TypeError TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function

const fs = require("fs");　これが有効になっていないのでしょうか。

Comment: @kn11n この回答で示しているコードで `require` しているのは `fs` では無く、`fs/promises` です。
使用している関数は、`fs.readFileSync` では無く、`fs.readFile` です。
まずは、コピペしてみてはいかがですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。requireでfs/promisesではエラーになるので、fsにしました。また、fs.readFileを試して、readFileSyncもあったのでそちらもやったので、後者を書いてしまいました。大変失礼いたしました。

Comment: `v14.16.1` で試しましたが、`fs/promises` がエラーになることは有りませんでした。
問題無く動いています。
ところで、質問に付けたコメントを確認いただけましたか？
どうもクライアント（ブラウザ）側のコードを開発なさっているのでは？ という気がして来ています。

Comment: 質問についていたコメント今読みました。いま、クライアント（ブラウザ）側を開発しております。気づくのが遅くなり、お手数をおかけしました。

Comment: お付き合いありがとうございました。一旦、圧縮はおいておきます。