# blobデータをJavaScript で圧縮する方法

Tags: javascript, node.js, gzip

blobデータを受け取った後にJavaScriptで圧縮して、他のアプリケーションサーバーに転送する事を実現しようとしています。その際に、下記のようにnode-gzipライブラリを使って、blobデータ（fileblobA）を圧縮しようとしました。node-gzipの入力データ型ではblobが扱えないようでしたので、arrayBufferに変更して、圧縮を試みました。しかし下記のコードではエラーになりました。

**動作環境**
Node.js + Vue.js

**コード:**

```
＝＝前略＝＝

const fileblobA = new Blob([result],{type:'application/octet-stream'})

const { gzip, ungzip } = require('node-gzip');
const gzipA = await gzip(fileblobA.arrayBuffer) ;
```

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Failed to execute 'arrayBuffer' on 'Blob': Illegal invocation
```

**解決しました**
【変更点】
・ライブラリの変更　node-gzip → zlib.js

**内容**
index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/zlib/zip.min.js"></script>
```

index.js

```
const arrayBuffer = await fileblobA.arrayBuffer();
    const zip = new Zlib.Zip();
    zip.addFile(arrayBuffer)
    const compressData = zip.compress();
    const fileblobZ = new Blob([compressData], { 'type': 'application/zip' });
```

Comment: 変数 `fileblobA` にどうやって何を入れたのか質問文に書いてください。

Comment: [前回のご質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/92075/3054)では、Node.js `v14.16.1` をお使いという事でした。
（実際にはブラウザ上の話だったのですが、それはそれとして）
そして、 `Blob` は [`v14.18.0` から](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_blob)だとマニュアルにはあります。
ですので、通常の手段だと `Blob` は使えないはずです。
これを可能にする外部ライブラリなどをご利用ならば、それも追記して下さい。
理想的には、[再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)を参考に再現可能なコードを記載して下さい。

Comment: お恥ずかしい話ですが、”ブラウザで動作”というのが勘違いでした。
ローカル環境でnode.jsのバージョンを上げて試してみます。

Comment: スクリプトタグがあるってことは node じゃなくブラウザ上で動作させたいってことでいいんですか？　サーバーサイド node から配信された vue 上でアップロードされたファイルをサーバー経由せずにクライアントサイドだけで圧縮して別のサーバーに転送したいってことですか？　それともいったんサーバーサイド(node)でうけとって node 内で圧縮したファイルを別サーバーに転送したいってことですか？　後者の場合圧縮はクライアント再度でやりたいのかサーバーサイドでやりたいのかどっちなんでしょうか

Comment: まずは、blobデータを圧縮する事が目的の一つでした（※）ので、そちらは解決です。
※：この点について言及していませんでした。混乱させてしまい申し訳ありません。
クライアント側で圧縮して、別サーバーへ転送する予定です。

Comment: 解決した場合は、解決方法を回答として投稿して下さい。
自己回答は[推奨されています](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)。
新たに疑問が生じた場合は、新規の質問として下さい。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。自己回答は推奨されているのですね。承知いたしました。

Answer (score 0):

以下の記述で、圧縮までは確認できました。

内容
index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/zlib/zip.min.js"></script>
```

index.js

```
const arrayBuffer = await fileblobA.arrayBuffer();
    const zip = new Zlib.Zip();
    zip.addFile(arrayBuffer)
    const compressData = zip.compress();
```